# Create a four columns div inside bootstrap thumbnail

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a problem creating three four columns div inside the bootstrap thumbnail. The problem is that if i use the col-xs-4 class, the text inside go out of the caption of bootstrap. And if i use three div inside another one, it works, but i can't align the text inside each div at the center. Any ideas? Currently i use this script:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
        <a href="profilo?id=<?php echo $dati['id'];?>" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="<?php echo $url1;?>" alt="Immagine profilo" />
          <span class="flag-diamond"></span>
          <div class="caption">
            <div class="esc_username"><span class="username"><?php echo $username;?></span><span class="hidden-xs age"><?php echo $anni;?> anni</span></div>
            <div class="esc_city"><?php echo $dati['citta'];?></div>
            <div style="width:100%">
              <div class="col-xs-4">TRY</div>
              <div class="col-xs-4">TRY</div>
              <div class="col-xs-4">TRY</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
```

and i get this: [image: Result]

but i want to do something like this:
 [image: Result i want]

[EDIT] 
If i add padding:0 to the three div, i get this: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Bootstrap you can nest divs which basically means that you can just add a surrounding row to your 3 divs.

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">TRY</div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">TRY</div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">TRY</div>
        </div>
```

The reason this should work is because `row` class has negative left and right margins which will automatically adjust itself to the container which, in your case, is the outer div.

Comment: @GiuseppeDePaola Glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

write class

```
.no-padding{
padding:0px;
}
```

Then apply where you don't want `padding` as follows

```
              <div class="col-xs-4 no-padding">TRY</div>
              <div class="col-xs-4 no-padding">TRY</div>
              <div class="col-xs-4 no-padding">TRY</div>
```

I hope this will solve your problem if not try adding `!important` to `padding` this will override other `padding` if it's overriding

```
.no-padding{
    padding:0px !important;
    }
```

Comment: yep it solved the problem, but now the div are out of the red box..middle inside and middle out

Comment: try add to box box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: i always write 3 classes. .no-padding, .no-padding-left, .no-padding-right

Answer (score 1):

please try this css code instead of col-xs-4:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">TRY</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">TRY</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">TRY</div>
```

Comment: it works, but the div now are middle inside the red box and middle out

Comment: can you please provide link in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

best way you can set the padding = 0 or you can set a background-color for the container div

like

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
    <a href="profilo?id=<?php echo $dati['id'];?>" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="<?php echo $url1;?>" alt="Immagine profilo" />
      <span class="flag-diamond"></span>
      <div class="caption">
        <div class="esc_username"><span class="username"><?php echo $username;?></span><span class="hidden-xs age"><?php echo $anni;?> anni</span></div>
        <div class="esc_city"><?php echo $dati['citta'];?></div>
        <div style="width:100%;background-color:#EEE;">
          <div class="col-xs-4">TRY</div>
          <div class="col-xs-4">TRY</div>
          <div class="col-xs-4">TRY</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```